# How to change the top directory for github repo

Tags: git, github

I inadvertently initialized a directory for a repo *two levels above* the directory I actually want to track.  As a result, when I do `git status`, it shows me a bunch of untracked files that I don't care about.  I know I can ignore them, but my repo shouldn't be at this level.  So my structure is like this:

```
--Parent_dir_1
  --Parent dir_2
    --DIRECTORY_I_WANT_TO_TRACK
      --file_1
      --file_2
```

My repo tracks files at the level or `Parent_dir_1`.  How can I change my repo's top line directory to `--DIRECTORY_I_WANT_TO_TRACK`?

Comment: Started as in everything is already committed? Do you want to remove the other directories from history too?

Comment: Yes, I have a couple commits already.  I had a sloppy directory tree so I got mixed up, but I didn't commit changes.  I moved some directories around and now I want to track those changes.  Yes, I do won't to remove the other directories from the history.

Comment: But `DIRECTORY_I_WANT_TO_TRACK` is always in the same place throughout the history – `Parent_dir_1/Parent dir_2/DIRECTORY_I_WANT_TO_TRACK`?

Comment: You're looking for `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter DIR_TO_TRACK -- --all`

Comment: (but do that in a separate clone probably?)

Comment: Why? it's easy to recover from mistakes.  `git fetch . +refs/original/*:*`.

Comment: Yeah maybe I was mistaken about my top line dir.  Running the `git filter-branch` command, I get the error the directory I want to filter by `is outside repository`, so not I'm confused.